# count(case when gender='M' then 1 end) as male_cnt can any one explain why we use then 1

Tags: sql

```
count(case when gender='M' then 1 end) as male_cnt
```

Can any one explain why we use `then 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement counts how many men are in the recordset. And `count()` counts everything that is not `null`. So you can use anything other than `NULL` in that `case`

```
count(case when gender='M' then 'hello' end)
```

There is no `else` part in the `case` which makes it automatically `null`. So this is the same:

```
count(case when gender='M' then 'hello' else null end)
```

Since all this is rather confusing I prefer to use `sum()` instead:

```
sum(case when gender='M' then 1 else 0 end)
```

This does the same but IMO is more readable.

In MySQL you can reduce that to

```
sum(gender = 'M')
```

since in MySQL the result of a comparision is `0` or `1` and you can sum that result up.